# rhythmbox and deepin both don't find my music directory. Is this some kind of permissions?

Tags: filesystem, rhythmbox

rhythmbox never added my music.  I thought it might be something wrong with the mp3 plugin, but vlc and the default movie player can play the mp3s.  I uninstalled rhythmbox and reinstalled in case it was a discovery issue on startup.

So in desperation, I installed deepin. That does not work either.  It now appears that neither one can see my music directory.

I have / mounted on an SSD and /big mounted on a large drive
neither program can see the drive.

Sure enough, when I copy to the main drive, rhythmbox can see the files.

There are no special permissions on these files.  They are owned by me.
How does rhythmbox not work with /big/Music ?

Answer (score 0):

Neither Rhythmbox or deepin can handle symbolic links.  When clicking on /home/user/Music -> /big/user/Music it does not behave the same even though the file requester follows the links.  By clicking on computer/big/user/Music it finds the directory.